# Range finder/Measuring tape using VHDL code on a fpga board

Tags: vhdl, fpga

i have to build a project that uses an FPGA with the software Modelsim. the project is a range finder or measuring tape.
I already know the basics of modelsim, but I've never done anything like this. the sensor that i am using is an Infra red proximity sensor. https://www.sparkfun.com/products/242 . I am aware that i will need to use an Analog to digital converter, in order for the fpga to recognize the sensor. this sensor also has to rely on is output voltage to determine the distance. the distance will then be displayed on an LCD screen. The problem i have is that i'm not sure where to start. 
so if anyone can give any advice, a sample code for this problem or anything it would be appreciated.

Comment: See [Get answers to practical, detailed questions](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) in the Tour, the bit about questions on an actual problem - "Specific programming problems, Software algorithms, Coding techniques
and Software development tools". This doesn't appear to be on topic for stackoverflow.  See the Help Center [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)  Perhaps this would be more appropriate on Stack Exchange's Electrical Engineer site?  See it's description of on topic questions [here](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0):

Each of these subjects can be a large subject of their own. As it is, you should narrow down your question into something more specific -- where are you stuck? That said, here are some thoughts to help you narrow your questions.

You have correctly identified what you need to do: utilize an A/D converter, and display range (distance) on an LCD screen.

Let's break what you need to do in a little more details.

- You need to interface with the A/D converter. For example, what pins are the data pins attached to on your FPGA? How do you need to clock the A/D? Basically, you need to figure out how to get digital samples into your FPGA logic.
- You need to convert your digital samples from a voltage to a range. A lookup table is an excellent way to do this. The input to the lookup table will be (digital) voltage, the output will be range.
- You need to learn how to interface with an LCD screen/panel.  At minimum, you are going to have to learn how to draw/redraw a few characters on the screen representing the range.

Once you have these 3 components, you need to tie them together. The A/D interface in the FPGA will periodically generate voltage values, the lookup table will convert voltages to range, and then you will display the range value on your LCD.